# Multi-Level (Two Level) Slide Menu Like Facebook iOS (iPhone Application)

Tags: ios, objective-c

How i can achieve two Level Slide Menu Like in the attached screen shot.I read many articles but all the Slide menu are just with one Level. i want menu like when in Slide menu some one click on Team it go to Sub-category (different teams)... any tutorial or please help. I am using andrewroycarter/SlideViewController but can't modify it upto two level.[image]

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/ipup/PPRevealSideViewController Check this demo if it helps to you

Comment: The problem is i can't get the navigation functionality in Menu when i add another view controller. Actually in each sdk the slide menu is not a navigation controller while it's just a Simple View Controller.

Comment: In case of Slide Menu as a navigation view then another view is push in a Full view instead of just Menu.

Comment: by using PPRevealSideViewController i have done this. u have to go through with examples provided in that and make changes

Answer (score 2):

Most slideout menus like this let you use any view controller for that left menu, not just a UITableViewController. So you just embed your UITableViewController in a UINavigationController and put the navigation controller as your slide out menu. I generally find [MFSideMenu](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu) to be useful, and it will allow you to use any view controller for your slide out menu.

Answer (score 0):

that shouldn't be very difficult. normally you can load any kind of viewcontroller in the side menu. so if you load there a navigationcontroller, you should be able to have more levels. try the slide menu from inferis:

[ViewDeck](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck)

Answer (score 0):

Please use this: [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController)

it is easy to use for sliding menu view :)

Comment: Yes they are easy for one Level. but problem is in second Level. i want two level of Slide menu with navigation...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

[MMDrawerViewController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController)

It might have what you need.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Gautham said, use [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController).
Just place Navigation Controller on top of "rear view controller" of SWRevealViewController, 
then to do simple push to open "second level" in menu.